# PHP image gallery and items in row

Tags: php

My images gallery has a xhtml like below:

```
<div class="row">

 <ul class="ul">

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

 </ul>

</div>
<div class="row">

 <ul class="ul">

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>

 </ul>

</div>
```

I want to do this: Insert only 3 `<li>` in `<ul>` and close the  after 3 `<li>`
What is the best way to do this?  position ($pos = 0, $pos++) , [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) or anything else?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it really matter? Why do you need "best" way? If you have 3 different spoons at home, would you ask someone which is the best of them to eat your meal? Don't you just get one of them, not not bothering yourself with choice? And even sensible choice?

Comment: I cant see like a php master. You can show me the right way Col.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. The only "right way" to be shown is just `"use templates for the output".` But particular template engine choice is on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare array of data.
We way you prepare it doesn't really matter.
You can use $pos++ and set column markers in the data array.
and then output in in the template like this:

```
<? foreach ($DATA as $row): ?>
<? if($row['ul']): ?>
<div class="row">
 <ul class="ul">
<? endif ?>
  <li><a href="<?=$row['url']?>"><img src="<?=$row['src']?>"></a></li>
<? if($row['/ul']): ?>
 </ul>
</div>
<? endif ?>
```

or you can use array_chunk and then use nested foreaches:

```
<? foreach ($DATA as $arr): ?>
<div class="row">
 <ul class="ul">
 <? foreach ($arr as $row): ?>
   <li><a href="<?=$row['url']?>"><img src="<?=$row['src']?>"></a></li>
 <? endforeach ?>
 </ul>
</div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

The latter one looks neat, I have to admit

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < 5; $i++){
  echo '<div class="row">    
           <ul class="ul">';
  for ($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
  echo '<li><a href="#"><img src=....></a></li>';  
 }
 echo '</ul>    
</div>';
}
```